# Why audio doesn't play if i use link from array in AngularJS?

Tags: html, angularjs, audio

I'm trying to play sound, if i use link to sound like this:

```
<audio controls ng-src="http://playerdemo.iainhouston.com/tests/BeBopAliens.mp3"></audio>
```

It's Ok, but when i try use link from `$scope.audioArray` like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="au in audioArrray">
  <audio controls ng-src="{{au.link"}}> </audio>
</div>


$scope.audioArray = [
{
   id: 1,
   link: "http://playerdemo.iainhouston.com/tests/BeBopAliens.mp3"
}];
```

it's doesn't play,I done the [Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/uTIga9?p=preview).
 Maybe somebody knows how i can resolve it ?
Thanks for your answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the error you get:

> Can't interpolate: {{au.link}} Error: [$sce:insecurl]
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.7/$sce/insecurl?p0=http%3...

It basically means that the interpolation has failed due to an untrusted resource you were passing.

More on this issue here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce

Try this:

```
var myApp = angular.module("myApp",[]);
myApp.controller("defCtrl", function($scope, $sce){
  $scope.audioArray = [
    {
      id: 1,
      link: $sce.trustAsResourceUrl("http://playerdemo.iainhouston.com/tests/BeBopAliens.mp3")
    }];
});
```